# Переносимость .NET приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Сегодня бросил дизайнеру .exe-шник, чтобы он мне xaml набросал, а он не может его запустить, вернее форма авторизации есть, а когда начинаем подключатся в базе, то выбивает программу.

Думали, что забыли поставить "%" для удаленного доступа в базе данных, оказывается, нет. Скорее всего на его машине не установлена .dll для работы с удаленной MySQL, так вот вопрос:

**Грамотным решением будет добавить этот .dll в папку с проектом и программно его прописывать в саму ОС? Или как?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что используете.

Если что-то из области ODBC - то почти с гарантией нужно будет регистрировать библиотеку, иначе к ней не достучитесь.

Если какой-то native-клиент, то хватит положить в папку с ЕХЕшником dll-клиента и libmysql.dll

Я конечно ярый сторонник непрописывания лишнего в системе, если без этого можно обойтись.